# dplyr "%>%" command : two in one line

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm willing to execute two SEPARTE %>% commands on an object (aov), is there an elegant way to do so in one command line ?

library(dplyr)
aov_bike %>% summary() %>% plot()

#The above doesn't work : I believe that it does the plot() on the output of the summary()

to be more clear : desired (no dplyr) :
library(dplyr)
summary(aov_bike)
plot(aov_bike)

Comment: Already tried `aov(yield ~ block + N*P*K, npk) |> plot(which=1)`?

Answer (score 6):

Look at [`magrittr::%T>%`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/tee.html), the examples do just that:

```r
library(magrittr)
aov_bike %T>%
  plot() %>%
  summary()
```

Or perhaps

```r
aov_bike %>% {
  plot(.)
  summary(.)
}
```

Comment: Thank you
Any other solution without an extra library ? :)

Comment: magrittr is already being used by dplyr, so it is guaranteed to be available, it's just that dplyr does not re-export all of its functions. Why no other library?

Answer (score 2):

The code in the question is not reproducible without `aov_bike` so use `npk` instead.  This runs `plot(npk)` and then forwards `npk` to `summary`.

```
library(dplyr)

npk %>%
  { plot(.); . } %>%
  summary
```

or if it is important to retain the order:

```
npk %>%
  { summary(.) %>% print; . } %>% 
  plot
```

or

```
npk %>% {
  summary(.) -> .temp
  plot(.)
  .temp
}
```